# How to make the keymap work to swap shift character with non-shift?

Tags: keymap, powertoys

My keyboar has on same key (') and (?), where (?) is activated with Shift key.
I want to swap those, so I activate (') with shift and (?) without shift.

PowerToys don't understand (?) as a key itself, so I have to map the shortcut for it, shift+'

So on PowerToys I mapped the shortcut shift(left)+' to ('). That worked.

Than I mapped the key (') to shift(right)+(')

I used different shifts (left and riht) so I can test it better.

But the result is, with any shift, or without shift, I always get the char (?)

Is there a way to make this work?

I also tried AutoHotkey, and had same issue.
Than I tried Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4 (on Windows 10), but it doesn't work at all, the keys do nothing when I try on "Keyboard Layout Testing".

Comment: Can you try a different (may I say normal) keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

This AutoHotKey script might do the job :

```
$?::
Send, '
Return
$'::
Send, ?
Return
```

Comment: I got an error when compiling for the second line, `==> Missing "'" Specifially: Send, '`,

Comment: I had tried this with autohotkey before, but got the result decribed in my question: `'::?` and `?::'`.

Comment: I tried this with similar keys from my keyboard and it worked, but perhaps yours is different. Which keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: from Portugal, the full name on Windows says "English (United States) - Portuguese". The (') + (?) key is two keys to the left of the Backspace key.

Comment: I installed "Portuguese (Portugal)" and had no problem when using the On Screen Keyboard. Perhaps you should install instead of "English (United States) - Portuguese", each language separately.